# spring-boot-starter-quartz jdbc vs memory jobstore in different environement

Tags: spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, quartz

I'm using  spring-boot-starter-quartz in a several environements project.

In local env I'd like to use memory jobstore(  `spring.quartz.job-store-type=memory`)
In all other env (preprod, prod ...) I'd like to use jdbc jobstore (`spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc`)

I'd like to put in  the default application.properties file all common properties  and override only usefulls properties in Local env properties file (application-local.properties)

So typically i will put this in application.properties

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false
```

And in application-local.properties

```
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.quartz.job-store-type=MEMORY
```

Quartz doesn't like this config. I'm facing exception like `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No setter for property 'tablePrefix'`

A trivial solution  consists in repeating the required properties in each file(I definitely don't want this solution).

How can i do otherwise ?

Comment: Is there anything to said for `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value`? Stick a default in?

Comment: i dont understand your comment Robert. I m looking for a way to organize properties file. I dont need to use any @value cause all that need to use as properties is offered by the starter. May be my question is not clear enough

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've misunderstood, I was thinking one way to solve your problem would be to put a default in the Java E.G. `@Value("${spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass:someDefault}") private String driverDelegateClass;` That way if you have a value in your properties file, it takes it, if not it defaults.

Comment: indeed  I can't do that.  I can't use at all driverDelegateClass property in local env(ie with memory jobstore). This seems to be  the starter or quartz library design problem (or at least a lack of flexibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approch was not the good one.
We can use jdbc jobstore with h2 database. the only thing that change is the driverDelegateClass. For h2 we need to use the driverDelegateClass `spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.HSQLDBDelegate.`

So this config will work with h2 database :

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.HSQLDBDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false
```